# Allowing users to sign in to Spring Security app via Google+ Sign in or OAuth 2.0

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We have an App which uses Spring Security along with username/password credentials.  We want to add the ability to use Google+ as an alternative sign in option.  In the user record, I would store the google user id along with the authenticated token rather than a password.

However, I have not had any success finding any docs or guidelines about how to do so.  The spring security docs provide a way of doing it via openId, but Google recommends using [Google+ Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow) or [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer).  I have found plenty of information about how to access oauth restricted resources from google, but none that use google as an authentication provider.

I may have to dig in and figure out how to implement my own spring authentication provider and user details solution for use with google authentication, but I would love it if someone could point me to where it has already been done, as I would be amazed if no one has done it before, and I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [pac4j](https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j) and [spring-security-pac4j](https://github.com/leleuj/spring-security-pac4j)